# How to display list of ATM in my route based on source and destination

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to display a list of ATM in my route(source & destination). I know there is a `placeAPI` to get nearby ATM but I wanna get list of ATM in my route and I have not been able to get it based on my source and destination. Is there any API or trick to achieve this? Any suggestions/answer would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Places API with `place type` [link](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=atm&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: This gonna show based on current location, I want to get it based on source and destination i.e. there would be two lat, lng

Comment: just replace the location={lat, long} with your current lat long.